# jquery mmenu close button undefined in chrome

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am trying to get mmenu to work like the demos, but the close button doesn't work in Chrome. It has #undefined when you click the button.

Here is the demo site: http://www.2015.line49.ca/

I tried adding isMenu: true but that didn't make any difference.

Here is my setup code:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#wpadminbar").addClass( "mm-slideout" );
    jQuery("#l49-mmenu").mmenu({
                    isMenu: true,
       extensions: ["effect-slide-menu", "effect-slide-panels-100", "border-full", "theme-dark", "multiline"],
                 offCanvas: {
        position  : "right",
        zposition : "front",
                    pageSelector: "> div:not(#wpadminbar)"
         },
                 navbars:[
                 {
                     position: "top",
                    title: "<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Logo-Baseline-white-transp.png\" alt=\"Company\">",
                    content: ["prev", "title", "close"],
                 },
                 {
                     position: "bottom",
                     content: "<span class='mmenu-left'>604 xxx xxxx</span> <span class='mmenu-right'><a href='mailto:xxx@domain.ca'>xxx@domain.ca</a></span>"
                 }]
            },
            {
             classNames: {
        selected: "current-menu-item"
     }
            });
        });
```

What do I need to do to get the close button working in Chrome?

Also when you close the menu it slides part way close and then disappears instead of nicely sliding all the way close. I can't find anything about how to fix that problem.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: remove the comma after `content: ["prev", "title", "close"]`

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the comment after: `codecontent: ["prev", "title", "close"] ` but it didn't make any difference. The x still doesn't work in Chrome. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue!
This is the workaround I came up with, to manually trigger the close event on the close button click

```
 var $mmenu = $('[MMENU_SELECTOR]');
 var mmenuApi = $mmenu.data("mmenu");

 $('body').on('click tap', '[CLOSE_BTN_SELECTOR]', function () {
     mmenuApi.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [a bug in the "close" button](https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/blob/master/src/addons/navbars/jquery.mmenu.navbar.close.js#L28) for the navbars add-on, it expects (and thus requires) your "page" DIV to have an ID.

Add an ID to the DIV that's considered to by the "page" to fix the issue.